# MVC4 Entity Framework 5 Many-To-Many Save Entity to Database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I've been stuck to long on this problem. I've looked at a lot of examples but i cant find what im looking for. Any help is appreciated.

I use the Code-First approach.

I've enabled migration and the database is fine [Student] - [StudentCourse] - [Course].

**Scenario**: I have two entites -> Student

> ```
> public class Student
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public virtual List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
> }
> ```

And Course

> ```
> public class Course
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string Description { get; set; }
>     public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Nothing fancy about that... Ive created a ViewModel ->

> ```
> public class StudentCourseViewModel
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>
>     public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
> }
> ```

**View:**

> @model Project.Web.Models.StudentCourseViewModel @{
>       ViewBag.Title = "Edit"; }
>
> ### Edit
>
> @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
>       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
>
> ```
> <fieldset>
>     <legend>Student</legend>
>
>     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
>
>     <div class="editor-label">
>         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
>     </div>
>     <div class="editor-field">
>         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
>         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
>     </div>
>
>     <div class="editor-label">
>         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Courses)
>     </div>
>       <div class="editor-field">
>     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count(); i++)
>     {
>         <div style="border: dotted 1px; padding: 5px; margin: 10px;">
>             @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Students[i].Id)
>
>             @Html.LabelFor(s => s.Students[i].Name[i + 1])
>             @Html.EditorFor(s => s.Students[i].Name)
>         </div>
>     }
> </div>
>
>     <p>
>         <input type="submit" value="Save" />
>     </p>
> </fieldset> }
> ```

**Controller Action:**

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public ActionResult Edit(CourseStudentViewModel model)
>     {
>         var course = db.Courses.Find(model.CourseId);
>         course.Name = model.CourseName;
>         course.Description = model.CourseDescription;
>         course.Students = model.Students;
>
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>
>             db.Entry(course).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
>             db.SaveChanges();
>
>             return RedirectToAction("Index");
>         }
>
>         return View(model);
>     }
> ```

(Maby this is were i go wrong...)

Anyway, ***I want to create a new Student with optional many courses*** (textboxes -> courseName)

How should i do this?

The main issue is that i always get null values (student is fine, List of courses = NULL) back from my view [httpPost]Create -action.

I'm in need of guidance how to make this approach possible.

Thx J!

Comment: Are the Courses present in your entity, just not in the ViewModel? Show the code for transforming your entity model into a view model.

Comment: Can you please post your view code?

Comment: @IronMan84 Ive added the view to the post

Comment: @KevinJunghans Ive added the controller edit action.

Comment: Can you also please post your Create action?

Comment: I just got the the edit action to almost work. No more NULL values. I get duplicates back to my database, but that ill figure out. I've updated my view and controller.

Comment: Is there any open question now after you got something to work? I really don't understand why you want to "create a new student" but show us an action that edits a course.

Answer (score 0):

Your entities are not setup correctly for a many-to-many relationship.  You need another entity to handle the many-to-many mapping. It would look something like this.

```
public class StudentsToCourses
{
   public int StudentId {get; set;}
   public int CourseId {get; set;}

   public virtual Student Student {get; set;}
   public virtual Course Course {get; set;}
}
```

Then your student model should be changed to this.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<StudentsToCourses> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

And your coursed model changed to this.

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<StudentsToCourses> Students { get; set; }
}
```

You also need to setup the foreign key relationship using the [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). It would look something like this.

```
public class StudentsToCoursesConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<StudentsToCourses>
{
    internal StudentsToCoursesConfiguration ()
    {
        this.HasKey(p => new {p.StudentId, p.CourseId});
        this.HasRequired(p => p.Student)
            .WithMany(p => p.Courses)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.StudentId);
        this.HasRequired(p => p.Course)
            .WithMany(r => r.Students)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CourseId);

    }
}
```

Comment: I get the [CourseStudent] relationship mapped by EF. Students and Courses PK's are stored in the table. I will use the Fluent API to setup my foreign keys later on. Right now i just want to be able to create (in this case) a Student with optional many Courses.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but i dont think that is what im looking for?

Comment: @JeppePepp - I am confused. Your title indicates you want a many-to-many relationship. Do you still want to maintain a many-to-many relationship or are you just trying to setup a one-to-many (one student can have many courses). Even for that you do not have your entities setup correctly.  How are you setting up the FK's, through SQL scripts?

Comment: I do want a many-to-many relationship. I use the code-first approach. One student can be involved in many courses. And One course can have many students. So my two tables of Students and Courses are populated with different data. My third table store the relationship between student and course. But i can add a course without students and the same for student. So its 0 to many. And 0 to many. The CourseStudent table is just holds the info for example all students in course x. You better understand my design? :)

Comment: He doesn´t need to have that entity if the many to many table doesn't require any other fields.